# Visual Basic 9 / Visual Studio 2008 IPAddress.Parse() doesn't work? Walked-Around

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

EDIT I accidentaly found a walk around to this problem... Adding the following line in the begining of the function solved the problem for some reason...

```
remoteIPAdress = remoteIPAdress & "END"
```

Hello.
I have a school assignment where I am supposed to build a simple TCP/IP messenger in Visual Basic... 
The problem is that when the client sends his IP in a request I've built ("LetMeIn\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"), even if the server receives the request as it should, it parses it completely wrong...

To be more exact, when I run this snippet I get these results:

```
Private Function findFreeIPEndPoint(ByVal remoteIPAdress As String) As IPEndPoint
    Dim ipEndPoint As IPEndPoint

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("LOL! The IP adress you try to parse is " & remoteIPAdress)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The parsed result is " & String.Concat(IPAddress.Parse(remoteIPAdress)))
    ipEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(remoteIPAdress), 1003 + topUniqueId)
    MessageBox.Show(String.Concat(ipEndPoint.Address))
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("The IP adress you got is " & String.Concat(ipEndPoint.Address))

    Try
        listener(ipEndPoint.Port - 1003).Start()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    topUniqueId = topUniqueId + 1

    Return ipEndPoint
End Function
```

Output:

LOL! The IP adress you try to parse is 192.168.1.65

A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.dll

If i change the following line

```
ipEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(remoteIPAdress), 1003 + topUniqueId)
```

to

```
ipEndPoint = New IPEndPoint("192.168.1.65", 1003 + topUniqueId)
```

I get this:

```
The IP adress you got is 229.64.116.11
```

Weird right?

Comment: And the one thing your code doesn't show is IPAddress.Parse...?

Comment: Hint: Before you can say that there is a bug in IPAddress.Parse, it's a good idea to *actually call the method*. If you can't parse the address because you then get an exception, perhaps you should focus on that problem first.

Comment: I edited my post to show the entire function... I call the method on line 4 and I get a Format Exception...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

With the edited question, my guess is that the input is not `"192.168.1.65`", but actually contains padding. Perhaps as simple as `"192.168.1.65 "`. Check the string ***carefully***. Heck, check the `.Length` first, then character by character.

---

Original answer based on the original question

I don't believe the output you are displaying is true, in part because of the missing LOL! But also, you have one of the numbers hard-coded; surely it should be:

```
 ipEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(remoteIPAdress),1003 + topUniqueId)
```

Also keep in mind the differnce between a local IP and a public IP. A 192.168 IP is your LAN. Remote clients won't have that, but will be using a public IP address translated via their router/proxy/whatever.

Comment: I forgot to add this line when I pasted my code... When this line runs, it throws me an Format Exception Unhandled/An invalid IP address was specified." exception... The hardcoded numbers were to show the string the server receives...

P.S. What I want, is to make this messenger work in a local network anyway, so it's ok...

Comment: Then your question makes no sense. You can't say "Bug in X, I get the wrong value", and then later on say that "To be honest, I can't call X because it crashes". Either you called it, and got the wrong value, or you didn't call it because it crashed, you can't do both at the same time.

Comment: I'm sorry If I didn't make myself clear... Now the post is complete, with all details...

Comment: @Loupax - and what is `remoteIPAdress.Length`?

Comment: @Marc Gravell MessageBox.Show(String.Concat(remoteIPAdress.Length)) shows me 13

Comment: @Loupax bingo! count the characters in 192.168.1.65 - it sounds to me like you have (as guessed) a rogue space on the end. Calling `.Trim()` should fix it; or, fixing the data to not have a space in the first place would be better

Comment: For a moment I thought we got it... I added the line remoteIPAdress = remoteIPAdress.Trim() at the beginning of the function, but I still get the same error and the same number of characters...

Comment: @Loupax - then look *character by character*... what are they? at the character level... in particular, the last one?

Comment: Well, I don't know why, but I just tried adding this line in the begining of my function and it stopped crashing! 
remoteIPAdress = remoteIPAdress & "END" 
Also it parses the IP address corectly... Go figure...